# How to persist / save program information

Tags: c#, reminders

I wrote a reminder program that runs automatically on startup. I want to know if there is a way, other than SQL-Server, to store event, date and time data. I do not want to use SQL-Server for this work, because I think SQL-Server is very big for this simple task. I think that I can use a file to store data in it. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part **where** to persist

From this [document (Managing User Data Deployment Guide, download)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/b/a/3ba6d659-6e39-4cd7-b3a2-9c96482f5353/Managing%20Roaming%20User%20Data%20Deployment%20Guide.doc):

> Windows uses the `Local` and `LocalLow` folders for application data
>   that does not roam with the user. Usually this data is either machine
>   specific or too large to roam.
>
> Windows uses the `Roaming` folder for application specific data, such
>   as custom dictionaries, which are machine independent and should roam
>   with the user profile.

So, I suggest using `AppData\Roaming` and persisting to a file since I consider a 'reminder app' to be user specific. And domain users for example would consider that valuable (syncing to server).

`Local` and `LocalLow` (the latter is used for low integrity mode, for applications with reduced privileges) would be more appropriate for some machine/installation specific data which can be calculated on-the-fly.

`Registry` seems great for some low amount of keys, but doesn't seem to be the best option for such use.

There is another option - `IsolatedStorage`, which should be used when mentioned options are not applicable, like when using ClickOnce deployments.

For the part **how** to persist your data to a file ... well, pick your favorite. You could use SQLite database which comes really lightweigt if you want more control and power or just use XML serialization to a file if you consider using SQLite an overkill. Or any of other viable options.

Comment: thanks for your answer,i want to know how sholud i save info into Roaming folder?i insert data into a file and then put in a folder that i makes for example reminder folder??

Comment: I already pointed you to this in my post. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Some common ways to store information:

- As a **file**. You have many options *where* you can store the file. For instance, user directory, and program directory. Further explanation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx). I prefer using a serializer (xml or json).
- As a **registry** entry. You store your information as key-value pairs.
- In a light-weight **database**:

  - RavenDB: its document-oriented, and stores data in json format
  - SQLite: relational; I recommend this [SQLite Admin](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) for managing purpose

Registry entries are more safe regarding user actions. On the other hand, files can be easily deleted.

You always have the option, to encrypt your information.

As a side note, you can also use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to declare variables to be stored in your registry. The code becomes something like this:

```
[RegistryBacking]
private bool _boolean;
```

*I can provide code later if you need it... when I'm home again.*

Answer (score 1):

XML. [.NET has classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3y47afh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that makes handling xml files easy. If you're saving structured data then XML might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I have for very similar reasons tried some easy to deploy databases and yet use the knowledge i have.

[VistaDB 3.x and 4](http://www.vistadb.net/) are my first choice because they are very much SQL Server compaible and allows me to switch to sql server anytime i like. This supports EF too!!!

Next is [db4o by Versant](http://www.versant.com/products/New_db4o.aspx)  which is very very handy. I use it mostly for quick prototyping but i have deployed to several small solutions and perfect for your kind of application.

I hope that helps!